# Create instance of a class on the fly

Tags: python

This may have a simple answer. I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Solution(object):
    s_list = []
    def add_number(self, number):
        self.s_list.append(number)
```

and some code:

```
chain_1 = [0,1,4]
chain_2 = [2,5,6]
solutions = []

for x in chain_1:
    solution = Solution()
    solution.add_number(x)
    for y in chain_2:
       if x < y:
           solution.add_number(y)
           solutions.append(solution)
           break
```

This of course updates the same instance of Solution everytime, what I need is 3 distinct instances of "Solutions":

```
sol1.s_list = [0,2]

sol2.s_list = [1,2]

sol3.s_list = [4,5]
```

but I get:

```
sol.s_list = [0,2,1,2,4,5]
```

Note: This is part of a larger problem, the number of "chains" is variable.

Comment: Make `s_list` instance variable instead of class variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make `s_list` a instance variable instead of class variable:

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s_list = []

    def add_number(self, number):
        self.s_list.append(number)
```